# Why does appendTo() and insertAfter() change font size?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery to insert a p tag after a h1 I get different font sizes from the two different methods appendTo() and insertAfter()

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/GnWcU/

```
$('<p></p>', {
    text: 'Sub Header 1',
    class: 'sh1' }).first().appendTo('h1'); 

$('<p></p>', {
    text: 'Sub Header 2',
    class: 'sh2' }).first().insertAfter('h1');
```

It appears as though the p appendTo() inherits its CSS from the element it's being appended to. If that is the case why doesn't insterAfter() also inherit?

Or if it's not inheriting the CSS what is happening here?

Comment: In your first example, you are wrapping `p` in `h1`, so `p` inherits from the `h1`.  Example: `<h1> Header <p>para</p></h1>`. For the second example, you are inserting the `p` *after* the `h1`.  Example: `<h1>header</h1><p>para</p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the HTML resulting from each operation.

`appendTo()` will insert the content into the selected element as the last *child* of that element. In your example, that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        Main Header
        <p class="sh1">Sub Header 1</p>
    </h1>
</div>
```

`insertAfter()` on the other hand, will insert the content *after* the selected element. In your example, that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Main Header</h1>
    <p class="sh2">Sub Header 2</p>
</div>
```

So the font-size on the first is larger, because it's *inside* the `<h1>` tag, and thus inherits it's styling.
On the second, it just *follows* the `<h1>` tag, so its styling is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

appendTo means put inside which will result in:
`<h1>Heading <p>paragraph</p> </h1>`

whereas insertAfter adds elemet after the element:

```
<h1>Heading</h1> <p>paragraph</p>
```

That's why you get larger font - it's inside the h1 and is treated as h1 which is wrong anyways. Just use insertAfter

Answer (score 0):

`appendTo` puts the `<p>` *into* your `<h1>` element. Since it's inside of the `<h1>`, it becomes a child of the header tag and will inherit its CSS properties.

`insertAfter` inserts the `<p>` right *after* the `<h1>` element. It's not a child, so it doesn't inherit any CSS properties from the `<h1>`.